# Rigid Body Problem, Active objects stay rigid, its not working

Tags: collision, rigidbody

Gravity seem off in the world. I made a big cube and a lot of little balls(50) at the top inside. I want them to fall to the floor, but things are off in my blender rigid body World. The balls are the active ones, and the cube the passive one. both have collider added with default settings.
When I tried to do a bake with the balls together in a collection and the cube  a constraints, things do not go the way I thought they would. A large portion of the balls stay rigid, and a few fly off in all directions but not to the floor. Any Ideas as to what setting i may have forgotten or what i did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The little balls are inside the big cube? That's not going to work with default settings. You either need to model the floor, walls and ceiling as separate objects, or set the cube's rigid body shape to mesh. While you're at it, set the balls' shape to sphere and choose good values for mass and bounciness.